# How to apply like, to search for email addresses, in a URN filter?

Tags: sql, vba, outlook

I need to search e-mail address from sender with asterisk.
e.g.  Joseph.The.First@hismail.com   ->  filter *The*@hismail.com

I have been inspired with code found on Microsoft or StackOverflow.

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%sketch%'"
```

This works for E-mails where subject contains sketch.

I modified URN schema to urn:schemas:httpmail:sentitems

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:from LIKE" & " = *The*"
```

Nothing found in current mailbox folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail Like '%joe@someaddr.com%'"
```

Alternatively...

```
Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail Like '%joe%'"
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is an invalid query: you are missing single quotes around the value and you are also using `LIKE` and `=` at the same time. Try

```
@SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:from" LIKE '%The*'
```