# Search Inbox by Subject, Sender and Date for each email address in Excel range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I search the inbox folder for given subject, sender from column 1 and date.

Based on the result it should populate rows in column 2 with Yes or No. But it populates all rows as No. I'm sure I should see at least one Yes.

The value of variable i is always nothing. Looks like it is a problem with filterstring variable.

[image]

```
Sub searchemailsreceived()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Dim ol As outlook.Application
Dim ns As outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As outlook.MailItem
Dim filterstring As String
Dim dmi As outlook.MailItem
Dim lstRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lstRow)
Set ol = New outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set dmi = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

For Each cell In rng
    filterstring = "@SQL=(""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail"" LIKE '%" & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2 & "%' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%This is my subject%' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '4/1/2021 12:00 AM')"
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(filterstring)
        If i.Class = olMail Then
            Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "Yes"
            GoTo landhere
        End If
    Next i
    Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "No"
landhere:
Next cell

Set mi = Nothing
Set dmi = Nothing
Set ol = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply like, to search for email addresses, in a URN filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224654/how-to-apply-like-to-search-for-email-addresses-in-a-urn-filter)

Comment: @niton: I checked the link you shared and changed the code from fromname to fromemail but still the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I tried a smaller and it worked but thank you.

```
Sub searchemailsreceived()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Dim ol As Outlook.Application: Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace: Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder: Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Dim filterstring As String
Dim lstRow As Long: lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lstRow)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For Each Cell In rng
    filterstring = "@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001f"" CI_STARTSWITH '%" & Cell.Value2 & "%' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%This is a subject%' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '1/1/2000 12:00 AM')"
    Range(Cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2 = fol.Items.Restrict(filterstring).Count
    filterstring = ""
Next Cell

Set ol = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following cleaned function (untested):

```
Sub SearchEmailsReceived()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application: Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Dim fol As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set fol = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lstRow As Long: lstRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lstRow)
    
    Dim i As Object, filterstring As String, Cell As Range

    Dim dmi As Outlook.MailItem: Set dmi = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    For Each Cell In rng
        filterstring = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail LIKE '%" & Cell.Value2 & "%' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%This is my subject%' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived >= '4/1/2021 12:00 AM'"
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "No"
        For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(filterstring)
            If i.Class = olMail Then Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes"
        Next i
    Next Cell
    
    Set dmi = Nothing
    Set ol = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

The answer linked by @niton shows the `SQL=urn...` doesn't contain quote marks so they have been removed. You may want to cut down the filterstring and test whether each additional AND statement causes issues though. Maybe comment out subject and date to test whether it finds any e-mails from the recipients first then work them back in the further requirements once you know the base works ok

Answer (score 0):

the fromemail schema didn't work for me. what worked for me is `""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001f"" CI_STARTSWITH '%" & Cell.Value2 & "%'`

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Demonstration with "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" and "proptag/0x0065001f".

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub searchemailsreceived_Demo()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace

Dim fol As Outlook.Folder

Dim folItems As Outlook.Items

Dim folItemsSQL As Outlook.Items

Dim folItems1SQL As Outlook.Items
Dim folItems2SQL As Outlook.Items
Dim folItems3SQL As Outlook.Items

Dim i As Long

Dim filterString1 As String
Dim filterString2 As String
Dim filterString3 As String

Dim filterStringSQL As String

Dim filterString1SQL As String
Dim filterString2SQL As String
Dim filterString3SQL As String

Dim lastRowColA As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Object
Dim foundFlag As Boolean

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRowColA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRowColA)

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set folItems = fol.Items
Debug.Print "folItems.Count..: " & folItems.Count
    
For Each cell In rng
    
    'filterString1 = """http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001f"" CI_STARTSWITH '%" & cell.Value2 & "%'"
    
    ' or
    
    ' Based on sample data, a filter without wildcards may be preferable.
    ' Col A = email addresses starting in row 2
    Debug.Print
    filterString1 = """urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail"" LIKE '" & cell.Value2 & "'"
    Debug.Print "filterString1 ..: " & filterString1

    filterString1SQL = "@SQL=(" & filterString1 & ")"
    Debug.Print "filterString1SQL: " & filterString1SQL
    
    Set folItems1SQL = folItems.Restrict(filterString1SQL)
    Debug.Print "folItems1SQL.Count.: " & folItems1SQL.Count
    
    ' Condition 1
    foundFlag = False
    For i = 1 To folItems1SQL.Count
        If folItems1SQL(i).Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print "i = " & i
            Debug.Print " - folItems1SQL(i).SenderEmailAddress: " & folItems1SQL(i).SenderEmailAddress
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "Yes"
            foundFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If foundFlag = False Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "No"
    End If
    
    
    ' Condition 2
    Dim strSubject As String
    strSubject = "test"
    
    Debug.Print
        
    filterString2 = """urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%" & strSubject & "%'"
    Debug.Print "filterString2 ..: " & filterString2
    
    filterString2SQL = "@SQL=(" & filterString2 & ")"
    Debug.Print "filterString2SQL: " & filterString2SQL
    
    Set folItems2SQL = folItems.Restrict(filterString2SQL)
    Debug.Print "folItems2SQL.Count.: " & folItems2SQL.Count
    
    foundFlag = False
    For i = 1 To folItems2SQL.Count
        If folItems2SQL(i).Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print "i = " & i
            Debug.Print " - folItems2SQL(i).Subject: " & folItems2SQL(i).Subject
            cell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = "Yes"
            foundFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
        
    If foundFlag = False Then
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = "No"
    End If
    
    
    ' Condition 3
    Dim strDate As String
    strDate = "2021/04/01 12:00 AM"
    
    Debug.Print
        
    filterString3 = """urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" & strDate & "'"
    Debug.Print "filterString3: " & filterString3
    
    filterString3SQL = "@SQL=(" & filterString3 & ")"
    Debug.Print "filterString3SQL: " & filterString3SQL
    
    Set folItems3SQL = folItems.Restrict(filterString3SQL)
    Debug.Print "folItems3SQL.Count : " & folItems3SQL.Count
    
    foundFlag = False
    For i = 1 To folItems3SQL.Count
        If folItems3SQL(i).Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print "i = " & i
            Debug.Print " - folItems3SQL(i).ReceivedTime: " & folItems3SQL(i).ReceivedTime
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value2 = "Yes"
            foundFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
        
    If foundFlag = False Then
        cell.Offset(0, 4).Value2 = "No"
    End If
    
    
    '  Condition 1 AND Condition 2 AND Condition 3
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print filterString1
    Debug.Print filterString2
    Debug.Print filterString3
    
    filterStringSQL = "@SQL=(" & filterString1 & " AND " & filterString2 & " AND " & filterString3 & ")"
    Debug.Print "filterStringSQL: " & filterStringSQL
    
    Set folItemsSQL = folItems.Restrict(filterStringSQL)
    Debug.Print "folItemsSQL.Count : " & folItemsSQL.Count
    
    foundFlag = False
    
    For i = 1 To folItemsSQL.Count
        If folItemsSQL(i).Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print "i = " & i
            Debug.Print " - folItemsSQL(i).SenderEmailAddress: " & folItemsSQL(i).SenderEmailAddress
            Debug.Print " - folItemsSQL(i).Subject...........: " & folItemsSQL(i).Subject
            Debug.Print " - folItemsSQL(i).ReceivedTime......: " & folItemsSQL(i).ReceivedTime
            Debug.Print
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "Yes"
            foundFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If foundFlag = False Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = "No"
    End If

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```