# Restrict items to Exchange senders

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook, exchange-server

I need to filter `Outlook` items by email address.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224654/how-to-apply-like-to-search-for-email-addresses-in-a-urn-filter):

```
Filter = "@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail Like '%joe@someaddr.com%'"
```

but it doesn't work if the sender is using Exchange. Maybe some different schema? I've searched the docs but can't find the answer.

Edit, to clarify, how that string is used:

```
Dim items As Outlook.Items = folder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a restriction on `SenderEmailType` being `"EX"`.

The filter would be either `[SenderEmailType] = 'EX'` or `@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1E001F" = 'EX'`

Comment: So how would the complete filter look like (schema/tag)?

Comment: See the updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to just filter by email type, I need specific sender by pattern... so far I have this: @SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" LIKE '%joe@someaddr.com%' OR ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1E001F" = 'EX' AND "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" LIKE '%joe@someaddr.com%'))
It doesn't work... yet.

Comment: 0x39FE001E is PR_SMTP_ADDRESS, it would not be set on a message. What you need is PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SMTP_ADDRESS - take a look at a message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button - it will show the property value as well as its DASL name).